# Separate Condition based coloring of different columns in bar-plot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have following data of particular candidates assessment again benchmark data. Find the csv file here:

```
Competencies    Desired Score
DRIVE           6       6.72
CUST ORIENTATION    6   6.58
INNOVATION  6   6.43
TEAM WORK   5   6.88
ANALYTICAL THINKING 6   7
LEADERSHIP  3   6.42
ASSERTIVENESS   3   6.73
PROBLEM SOLVING 4   6.73
IMPLEMENTATION & EXECUTION  6   6.85
WORKING KNOWLEDGE   6   5
BU KNOWLEDGE    3   4.58
FU KNOWLEDGE    3   4.7
KNOWLEDGE OF THE BUSINESS ENVIRONMENT   4   4.72
```

I have to make a horizontal bar plot like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleQf.png

Where color of bench mark column is fixed as blue and color of score column is based on the following condition:

```
cols <- ifelse(import1$Score>import1$Desired,"green",
           ifelse(import1$Score>=(0.96*import1$Desired) & import1$Score<import1$Desired,
                  "yellow", "red"))
```

How do I do it in bar plot so barplot takes the colors as mentioned below (I have manually input it):

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(import1[,1:2])),horiz=TRUE,
    col=c("blue","green","blue", "green","blue", "green","blue", 
          "green","blue","green","blue", "green","blue","green" ,"blue",
          "green","blue", "green","blue", "red","blue","green","blue", "green","blue", "green" ),cex.names=0.5,las=1,cex.axis=0.6,beside=TRUE,border=NA)
```

I want some condition based approach in `col`.

Edit:
Additional Query

If I have multiple scores for same set of competencies, how do I make separate set of charts on above mentioned condition.

```
Competencies    Desired Score 1 Score 2 Score 3
DRIVE           6       6.72        5.2 6.6
CUST ORIENTATION    6   6.58    6   7.6
INNOVATION  6   6.43    4.2 7
TEAM WORK   5   6.88    5.4 7.8
ANALYTICAL THINKING 6   7   4.6 7
LEADERSHIP  3   6.42    5.8 7
ASSERTIVENESS   3   6.73    4.8 6.4
PROBLEM SOLVING 4   6.73    6   6.6
IMPLEMENTATION & EXECUTION  6   6.85    6.2 6
WORKING KNOWLEDGE   6   5   3.6 5.4
BU KNOWLEDGE    3   4.58    3.8 4.4
FU KNOWLEDGE    3   4.7 4   4.6
KNOWLEDGE OF THE BUSINESS ENVIRONMENT   4   4.72    4   4.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the colors you want in `cols` you can create the vector you want by first generating enough `"blue"` values like this:

```
blues <- rep("blue",length(cols))
```

and then combine this vector with the other vector to get the colors you want using:

```
colors <- as.vector(rbind(blues,cols))
```

after which your plot can be created by:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(import1[,2:3])),horiz=TRUE,
    col=colors,cex.names=0.5,las=1,cex.axis=0.6,beside=TRUE,border=NA)
```

**Edit:**

Combining all of this into a function looks like this:

```
calcCols <- function(df,score) {
    cols <- ifelse(df[,score]>df$Desired,"green",
            ifelse(df[,score]>=(0.96*df$Desired) & df[,score]<df$Desired,
                   "yellow", "red"))
    blues <- rep("blue",length(cols))
    as.vector(rbind(blues,cols))                
}
```

After which you can create the three charts you would want with the new data using:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(import1[,2:3])),horiz=TRUE,
    col=calcCols(import1,"Score.1"),cex.names=0.5,las=1,cex.axis=0.6,beside=TRUE,border=NA)

barplot(t(as.matrix(import1[,2:3])),horiz=TRUE,
    col=calcCols(import1,"Score.2"),cex.names=0.5,las=1,cex.axis=0.6,beside=TRUE,border=NA)

barplot(t(as.matrix(import1[,2:3])),horiz=TRUE,
    col=calcCols(import1,"Score.3"),cex.names=0.5,las=1,cex.axis=0.6,beside=TRUE,border=NA)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am facing another hurdle in the same set of data. I have put it in additional Query. Please check.